# Angular Material Table dynmaic Vertical Height limit

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to build a dashboard with Angular 15 that also includes a Material Table; if I give the table a maximum height in px, the body complies with the limitations and uses a scrollbar for the rows of the table; however, I want to use a grid and if I set the height accordingly to 100% (based on 1fr comming from the parent grid), then I get a scrollbar and an overflow on the parent, even though I also set height 100% there.

Why is the material table row container not respecting the parent height?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve honestly. Besides, can you please create a Stackblitz to reproduce the issue and better describe what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hey, thank you, I did play around a bit with stackblitz; did never create one before:
https://angular-xc7sat.stackblitz.io
Please change the inline css in line 24 to see the table fills more than expected

Comment: Sadly this link is just the runnable. Can you please give me the project's url, so I can have a look into it? Thank you.

Comment: It should be runnable but you need the edit link for it to change the Property... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xc7sat?file=src/main.ts
First Time Mistake :o

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the Stackblitz.

I've looked into it and managed to achieve this:

[image]

It's hard to see but the scrollbar is not on the body but on the `table-content`. This way the table expand as much as it can while respecting the height of the div `Some content`.

Using `height: 100%` only works when there is a set height somewehere else in the hierarcy tree. That's why personally I always set the `body` to be `100svh`.

Anyway, to achieve this behaviour what's needed is a structure like that:

```
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="table-menu">
        Some content
    </div>
    <div class="table-content">
        <table mat-table>
            <!-- Your content -->
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

.table-menu {
    height: 20px;
}

.table-content {
    height: calc(100% - 20px);

    table {
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
}
```

This can be useful when you have a set height.

---

Achieving the same result using a more dynamic approach it's a bit more different, but still easy. This is the result:

[image]

What we have here are two divs both of `50vh` height. The first just has some text, the second hold inside the `mat-table` at `100%` of the parents height.

The structure is the following:

```
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="table-menu">
        Some content
    </div>
    <div class="table-content">
        <table mat-table>
            <!-- Your content -->
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

.page-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 50vh 50vh;

    .table-content {
        overflow-y: auto;

        table {
          height: 100%;
        }
    }
}
```

By changing the line `grid-template-rows: 50vh 50vh;` accordingly to your needs you can see how the table react according to the parent's height.
IE: `grid-template-rows: 20vh 80vh;` will procude a result like that:

[image]

---

Few notes:

In the global style, I've added these lines:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100svh;
}
```

Setting that all the elements (normally, in before and after) with no margin or padding isn't necessary at all for this example, but I think it's mandatory for any application to have it.

Setting html and body both to 100svh allow you to use `height: 100%` more easily, without too many headaches.

I've also moved the `mat-paginator` in the second div but outside the `table` tag.

```
<div class='table-content'>
  <table mat-table>
     ...
  </table>
  <mat-paginator></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

[This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-es8yw3?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css) should redirect you to the updated example. If it doesn't [here's a new one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cq7jha?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

If you have questions feel free to ask me!